# GWT Editor: How to set last modified time on the entity when saved?

Tags: gwt, gwt-editors

Suppose at client side i have an Entity proxy to edit by the UI and when i click save button, the last modified time is save in the entity proxy as a field.

```
 //start
 MyEntityProxy proxy = getProxy();//fetched from server
 Request<Void> saveRequest = requestFact.myEntityProxyRequest().save(proxy);
 editorDriver.edit(proxy, saveRequest.getRequestContext());
 editorDriver.flush();

 //user modifies UI
 ....

 //save
 editorDriver.flush();
 saveRequest.fire();
```

The problem is, where to insert the proxy.setLastModifiedTime(data) call? I always got

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: The AutoBean has been frozen.
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're using your `proxy` variable between `flush()` and `fire()`, you first have to `edit()` it.

```
proxy = saveRequest.getRequestContext().edit(proxy);
```

This is done automatically within `editorDriver.edit(…)` but it keeps the returned value private.

Comment: HI, did that mean there is no way to set last modified time by hand when using `editorDriver.edit(…)` just because it keeps the returned value private?